# Deserialize null

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have a WCF REST webservice and have datacontracts with several string properties. I want to be able accept null values (as below) however setting the property to a nullable string (`string?`) in the contract gives a compiler error. When i leave the datacontract properties as strings it errors when the client sends me xml like below. The error it gives is a serialisation errror. Is what im trying to do possible?

```
<myclass>
<somestring xsi:nil="true" />
<myclass>
```

Answer (score 2):

- A string doesn't have to be delcared as nullable as it is a reference type not a value type and therefore can be null anyway. `string str = null;` compiles just fine.
- That's not valid XML, however that could cause a runtime error (not compile time)

Try this

```
<myclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <somestring xsi:nil="true" />
</myclass>
```

Comment: Your XML isn't valid either :). xsi is not defined.

Comment: Wahaha, fair enough. The question has been updated since my answer so I need to make some changes to the lot.

Answer (score 0):

You might try omitting the element or the attribute (*I can't remember if WCF will accept this*):

```
<myclass>
</myclass>
```

The main problem is you have not defined the `xsi` namespace. Assuming that `myclass` is the root of your document:

```
<myclass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <somestring xsi:nil="true" />
</myclass>
```

Remember that `xml` (`http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`) and `xmlns` (`http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`) are the only namespaces and prefixes provided by XML by default.

You could also use [`XmlSerializerFormatAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.xmlserializerformatattribute.aspx) and use the old `System.Xml.Serialization` implementation - which does recognise `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`.

**Further Information**

- I assume you made a typo with your XML example - just keep in mind that your closing tag is incorrect.
- `String` cannot be used in `Nullable<T>` because it is not a value type - you can assign `Null` to it because it is a reference type. Use `String` in your `DataContract`.